# Microsoft SQL Server - Convert column values to list for SELECT IN

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this (3 int columns in one table)

```
Int1 Int2 Int3
---------------
 1    2    3
```

I would like to run such query with another someTable:

```
SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE someInt NOT IN (1,2,3)
```

where 1,2,3 are list of INTs converted to a list that I can use with SELECT * NOT IN statement

Any suggestions how to achieve this without stored procedures in Micorosft SQL Server 2019 ?

Comment: I'm just lost.  "one table".  "some table".  What do these refer to?  Where do the "1", "2", and "3" come from?  Do those constants have some relationship to the columns in the first table you mention?

Comment: There are two tables. One hold 3 columns with ints, and another one (the "sometable" having a "someInt" column in it) wanting to use the agregated "list" from that table to make a query

Comment: @SOCAR A table has rows, each of which have a fixed set of columns. Don't make things more unclear by making assumptions which you do not define (just a single row?). You seem to have a schema problem - your table is not properly normalized. You can work around this, but why not fix the problem once and for ever? Anytime you see column names that share a common name with some sort of increment is a sign of schema issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want rows in some table that are not in one of three columns of another table, then use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from sometable t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t.someint in (t2.int1, t2.int2, t2.int3)
                 );
```

The subquery returns a row where there *is* a match.  The outer query then rejects any rows with a match.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you actually want a `NOT EXISTS`?

```sql
SELECT {Your Columns}
FROM dbo.someTable sT
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM dbo.oneTable oT
                  WHERE sT.someInt NOT IN (oT.int1,oT.int2,oT.int3));
```

An alternative method would be to unpivot the data, and then use an equality operator:

```sql
SELECT {Your Columns}
FROM dbo.someTable sT
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM dbo.oneTable oT
                       CROSS APPLY (VALUES(oT.int1),(oT.int2),(oT.int3))V(I)
                  WHERE V.I = sT.someInt);
```